# Is はの even possible?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, particle-の

I found this sentence on jisho.org:

```
税制改革はの圧力が高まっている

The pressure for tax reform is growing.
```

And I'm wondering if this is a typo. Having both は and の together somehow sounds a bit odd to me. I would expect it to be either

```
 税制改革の圧力が高まっている
```

or

```
税制改革は圧力が高まっている
```

Can someone please tell me which forms are correct?

Comment: It's a sentence from Tatoeba. https://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/142476 the only option for other people's sentences is to leave a comment for the person.

Comment: Personally, based on what I know, I'd say it's only の. However, when doing some research about that sentence, I found that weblio has the sentence as well and also has the はの, so I don't think it's a typo. My next best guess as to why they use はの would be because it is official/formal speech. Don't think this helps but that's how far I got.

Comment: It's a typo. The sentence is 税制改革への圧力が高まっている or 税制改革の圧力が高まっている.

Comment: @spytastic the sentence on weblio is taken from the same one as what I linked to. The Tanaka Corpus takes from Tatoeba as well. People might not be aware when they make these sentences on Tatoeba that they get disseminated everywhere (and assumed to be correct by many people)

Comment: @YuuichiTam Thank you! If you post it as an answer I can accept it and upvote!